# Error while building TensorFlow from source

Tags: tensorflow, compiler-errors, bazel

I am trying to build TensorFlow cpu only r1.11 from source on a Debian OS  following this tutorial: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source

I installed bazel as indicated using this tutorial https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/install-ubuntu.html ***from the binary installer as recommended.***

Then I followed each step and everything worked fine until this command:

```
bazel test -c opt -- //tensorflow/... -//tensorflow/compiler/... -//tensorflow/contrib/lite/...
```

It shows me this error:

```
ERROR: error loading package '': Encountered error while reading extension file 'closure/defs.bzl': no such package '@io_bazel_rules_closure//closure': The native http_archive rule is deprecated. load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive") for a drop-in replacement.
Use --incompatible_remove_native_http_archive=false to temporarily continue using the native rule.
ERROR: error loading package '': Encountered error while reading extension file 'closure/defs.bzl': no such package '@io_bazel_rules_closure//closure': The native http_archive rule is deprecated. load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive") for a drop-in replacement.
Use --incompatible_remove_native_http_archive=false to temporarily continue using the native rule.
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.088s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (0 packages loaded)
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (0 packages loaded)
```

I read online that this is likely related to bazel. So I tried reinstalling bazel using the ***Using Bazel custom APT repository*** but I got the same error.

Comment: @jdehesa thanks man! You unblocked me. If you can put an answer, I will mark as solved. It might help other people

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of version 1.12.0, TensorFlow uses some deprecated Bazel features that are being completely dropped in recent versions of Bazel. Instead of using the most recent version, try using an older one for now. I was able to build TensorFlow 1.12.0 on Windows using Bazel 0.18.1, most likely that should work with TensorFlow 1.11 too.

Comment: hope that is [Bazel 0.18.1](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/releases) ?

Comment: @SathyamoorthyR Oh yes, fixed it, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @jdehesa. Even I was struggling to build the tensorflow using from scratch. I tried different versions, 0.26,0.21,0.19.1 and finally it worked with 0.18.1. So, it is a bazel issue rather than Tensorflow. TF_version=1.12.0